# CompletableFuture being created and waited on inside a forloop

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm trying to loop over a bunch of files and process them with long running tasks. Using `CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b)` I can see in the logs that two threads a processing the same file rather than one each.

```
private void fileScan() {
    final Set<Video> videos = videoService.findAllVideoFiles();

    for (Video video : videos) {
        final CompletableFuture<Thumbnail> cover = thumbnailService.createCover(video);
        final CompletableFuture<List<Thumbnail>> thumbnails = thumbnailService.createThumbnails(video);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(cover, thumbnails);

        try {
            video.setCover(cover.get());
            video.setThumbnails(thumbnails.get());

            videoRepository.save(video);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Set` is built from `Set<File> files = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();`

And the processing methods are set as `@Async` but the logs are showing

```
 START >> Thread thumbnail_thread_1 >> Video Dogs.mp4
 START >> Thread thumbnail_thread_2 >> Video Dogs.mp4
 END >> Thread thumbnail_thread_2 >> Video Dogs.mp4
 END >> Thread thumbnail_thread_1 >> Video Dogs.mp4
 START >> Thread thumbnail_thread_3 >> Video Cats.mp4
 START >> Thread thumbnail_thread_4 >> Video Cats.mp4
 END >> Thread thumbnail_thread_3 >> Video Cats.mp4
 END >> Thread thumbnail_thread_4 >> Video Cats.mp4
```

Is there a proper pattern I've missed, or can my logs just not be trusted?

Comment: What do you think `CompletableFuture.allOf(cover, thumbnails);` does?

Comment: Is it that you're expecting `thumbnailService.createCover` and `thumbnailService.createThumbnails` to run concurrently and process a different file each?

Comment: I was expecting `CompletableFuture.allOf` to "wait" for lack of a better word until both processes are complete, then continue.

Comment: @ernest_k I would like to process one file completely, so expecting each of the cover and thumbnail processes to have the same file

Comment: Then in that case you have to make the combining future block. Something like `CompletableFuture.allOf(cover, thumbnails).join()`

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)), `allOf` returns a `CompletableFuture` that _completes_ when all the others complete. If you want to _block_ until this to happens you have to `join` or `get` on the returned `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Calling `CompletableFuture.allOf()` seems a bit redundant to me in this case, given that you call `get()` on both of these futures immediately afterwards and are not doing anything with the `allOf` future.